# Are the dyno restarts on Heroku simultaneous?

Tags: heroku

I read on Herokus website that dynos will be restarted about every 24 hours.
If you have for example two web-dynos is there a chance that they will be restarted simultaneously?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to heroku:

> "The cycling happens once every 24 hours **(plus up to 216 random
>   minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at
>   the same time)**."

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos

Answer (score 2):

Heroku restarts dynos randomly -- sometimes multiple times per day. Don't count on it being simultaneous!

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I am rather worried that the dynos restart simultaneous. In that case a request could be left "unanswered"

Comment: Incoming HTTP requests are buffered by the Heroku load balancer -- so in the event all of your dynos are restarting the incoming request will be 'held' until a dyno is available to process it :)

Comment: Any idea if it's possible to control Heroku so it stops requests from coming in to a dyno a specified amount of time before issuing the restart command?

Comment: You can do this by turning maintenance mode on (eg: heroku maintenance:on and heroku maintenance:off) -- this will make Heroku serve up a static maintenance page to users, and not forward any incoming requests to your dynos.