# What's the recommended way of dealing with Heroku's dyno restarts on a worker?

Tags: heroku

I'm familiar with Heroku's [policy on dyno restarts](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting) (once every 24 hours, if underlying hardware fails, etc).

I've also looked elsewhere on Stackoverflow and found questions like
[Controlling Heroku's random dyno restarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665364/controlling-herokus-random-dyno-restarts).

Our apps are good from a web perspective – sessions are handled via external database and multiple dynos balance the load perfectly. Restarts aren't an issue there. The issue is **workers**. For example, our worker receives a message and begins processing a job. It's 99% done, awaiting some final asynchronous request to return, and it receives SIGTERM. Before it can even clean up the job, the process is killed. The code can handle local cleanup for a job that needs to be restarted, but external services can't really be part of the transaction.

For example, if a report was built and an email was sent, but some 3rd async operation didn't complete before SIGTERM, I can't really roll back that transaction. For hardware failures or other rare events, it's understandable that a multi-step transaction could get truncated, but with Heroku's policy it seems that I need to assume this will happen at least once a day. Can anyone help me get a better grip on this problem?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, each worker dyno will be freshly started when its job starts. Yes, hardware failure etc. can happen but most of the time your worker should be able to run for about a day before being restarted. Do you have jobs that take longer than 24 hours to run?

Comment: The worker dyno is started when the app deploys and runs for 24 hours before Heroku cycles it. It processes jobs whenever it receives a message. The jobs could take anywhere from a few seconds to several minutes.

Comment: What messaging system are you using / because you should be able to handle this through acknowledging the message at a later stage. Also - are your operations idempotent?

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'm using my own code but am interested in RabbitMQ. "acknowledging the message at a later stage" how does this relate to a job that's terminated in the middle of asynchronous tasks? Regarding idempotency, yes, however asynchronous operations like sending an email can't realistically be controlled. I suppose any asynchronous operations could be queued and then rolled back, but that makes this many orders of magnitude more complicated.